# Mobile Video Doesnt Work without controls

Tags: html, video

The video player won't show on my mobile device **(Chrome, Android P, OnePlus 6)**, while it does show on another, almost identical **(Chrome, Android P, OnePlus 5T)** device. iOs devices do show the player too.

```
<video muted autoplay>

           <source src="video/doc.webm" type="video/webm">
           <source src="video/doc.mp4" type="video/mp4">

</video>
```

The video tag is visible in the inspector.
If I add the controls, it becomes visible on my device.

```
<video muted autoplay controls>

       <source src="video/doc.webm" type="video/webm">
       <source src="video/doc.mp4" type="video/mp4">

</video>
```

Why is the video invisible on some devices, even when they are almost identical?

I prefer to keep the controls invisible.

Comment: Just provide a custom look for the video element.

Comment: @gugadev What do you mean by custom look?

Comment: You can make a custom player built on HTML video. Just need to add a bit of css and js. The browsers show the player different per platform.

Answer (score 1):

> *"Why is the video invisible on some devices, even when they are almost identical?"*

Don't know, but it's very common. It's frustrating at times but it's job security for us developers

---

### Solution

Try adding controls (or removing controls) when one of the loading events triggers, here are the events in order:

> 1. `loadstart`
> 2. `durationchange`
> 3. `loadedmetadata`
> 4. `loadeddata`
> 5. `progress`
> 6. `canplay`
> 7. `canplaythrough`

Test each one, one at a time until you succeed or if you don't, you can edit your question with the extra actions you have taken. The demo below adds an event listener to a single video and then once triggered by the `loadstart` event, it will add controls to the video tag (or remove controls see comments in demo).

---

### Demo

```js
document.querySelector('video').addEventListener('loadstart', function(e) {
  e.target.controls = true;
  // This is an alternate
  // e.target.setAttribute('controls', true);
  /* To remove controls */
  // e.target.controls = false;
  // or
  // e.target.removeAttribute('controls');
});
```

```html
<video muted autoplay>
  <source src="https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/005609.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `playsinline`

```
<video muted autoplay playsinline>

       <source src="video/doc.webm" type="video/webm">
       <source src="video/doc.mp4" type="video/mp4">

</video>
```